# Wordpress - не выводятся виджеты в сайдбар

Tags: wordpress, виджет, themes, sidebar

Создаю свою тему на wordpress. Столкнулся с проблеммой, не выводятся виджеты в сайдбаре, причем в адми панели виджиты есть и добавлять удалять их можно, на самом сайте они не отображаются.

Сам sidebar.php

```
<aside class="aside">
    <div class="about">
       <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/about-us.png" alt="" class="about__img" width="250" height="250">
       <h2 class="about__title">Какой то текст</h2>
       <p class="about__info">Описание какого то текста</p>
       </div>    
            <div id="true-foot" class="sidebar">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar('right-sidebar');
                echo 'Новый сайдбар'; ?>
            </div>    
</aside>
```

Фрагмент когда из function.php

```
add_action('widgets_init', 'register_freshtheme_widgets');
function register_freshtheme_widgets() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Боковая панель',
        'id' => 'right-sidebar',
        'description' => 'Боковая панель виджетов',
        'class' => 'aside',
        'before_widget' => '<li class="aside__item>',
        'after_widget' => '</li>\n',
        'before_title' => '<span aside__item-title>',
        'after_title' => '</span>',
        'before_sidebar' => '',
        'after_sidebar' => '',
    ));
}
```